# Stuff query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    AcNumber,   
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '::' + (REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([master].dbo.Mig_fn_cutString([master].dbo.Mig_fn_StringReduce(UPPER(NomiName)),35,',',1,'Y','F'))),',',' '))
                   FROM [DepNominee] DPN
                   WHERE (AcNumber = DPN.AcNumber)
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) AS JBL_NOM_NAME,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '::' + (REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([master].dbo.Mig_fn_cutString([master].dbo.Mig_fn_StringReduce(UPPER(FHName)),35,',',1,'Y','F'))),',',' '))
                   FROM [DepNominee] DPN
                   WHERE (AcNumber = DPN.AcNumber)
                   FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) AS NOM_FATH_NAME,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '::' + (REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([master].dbo.Mig_fn_cutString([master].dbo.Mig_fn_StringReduce(UPPER(MHName)),35,',',1,'Y','F'))),',',' '))
                   FROM [DepNominee] DPN
                   --WHERE (AcNumber = DPN.AcNumber)
                   FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) AS NOM_MOTH_NAME
FROM 
    [DepNominee] DPN
GROUP BY 
    AcNumber, NomiName
```

That is my code, I want to see all data according my AccountNumber. But I see only one data repeating all the time in different account number. I attach the image:

[image: My output:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are using the alias `DPN` in more than one place, causing your subqueries not to be correlated.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    AcNumber,   
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '::' +     (REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([master].dbo.Mig_fn_cutString([master].dbo.Mig_fn_StringReduce(UPPER(NomiName)),35,',',1,'Y','F'))),',',' '))
               FROM [DepNominee] DPN2
               WHERE (DPN.AcNumber = DPN2.AcNumber)
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) AS JBL_NOM_NAME,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '::' +  (REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([master].dbo.Mig_fn_cutString([master].dbo.Mig_fn_StringReduce(UPPER(FHName)),35,',',1,'Y','F'))),',',' '))
               FROM [DepNominee] DPN2
               WHERE (DPN.AcNumber = DPN2.AcNumber)
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) AS NOM_FATH_NAME,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '::' + (REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM([master].dbo.Mig_fn_cutString([master].dbo.Mig_fn_StringReduce(UPPER(MHName)),35,',',1,'Y','F'))),',',' '))
               FROM [DepNominee] DPN2
               --WHERE (DPN.AcNumber = DPN2.AcNumber)
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) AS NOM_MOTH_NAME
FROM 
    [DepNominee] DPN
GROUP BY 
    AcNumber, NomiName
```